# JK flip-flop: What is the difference between clear and J=0, K=1, rising clock?

Tags: clock, flipflop, ttl

I'm trying to create a [`Program Counter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) using some JK flip-flops.

I have two different way to do that:

- Use some `74LS73` (dual JK flip-flop with clear):

  [image: 74LS73]
- Use both `74LS10` (triple input NAND) and `74LS00` (double input NAND):

  [image: Cross-coupled NAND gates with clock]

Using the first integrated circuit will be easier, but this isn't the problem.

My doubt is about the Clear pin in `74LS73`: I know it will reset the flip-flop but also the combination J=0 and K=1 on a rising clock edge should do it...

So, **what is the difference between the Clear pin and J=0, K=1, rising clock**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asynchronous vs. synchronous

**asynchronous** is easy for resetting the flip flop at power up. It does not require a clock to reset the flip flop.

**synchronous** is easy for changing the output to 0 during normal operation, it requires a clock to propagate to the output.

I could imagine if you want to build a counter, you want an easy way to reset all outputs to 0 at power up. The reset pin is ideal for that, because at power up without reset the outputs will be undefined/random. With the reset pin a power on reset doesn't require the input logic gates to get more complex.